# Finding Particular Solutions to Non-Homogeneous Recurrence Relations

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Could anyone assist me in solving the following recurrence relations?

$a_n = 3a_{n-1} - 2a_{n-2} + 2^n n^2$

$b_n = -nb_{n-1} + n!$

Specifically, I am not sure how to find the particular solutions to such relations once a homogeneous solution is given?

Comment: Are there any initial conditions?

Comment: There are not actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last part of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332180/12042) tells you how to deal with the first problem.

For the second, we need initial conditions. If $b_0=0$, however, you can do it almost by inspection: taking $b_0=0$ generates the sequence $\langle 0,1!,0,3!,0,5!,\dots\rangle$, and it’s not hard to guess and then show by induction that

$$b_n=\begin{cases}0,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\n!,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\end{cases}$$

is a solution. In fact, you can extend that idea to get a general solution:

$$\begin{align*}
&b_0=b_0\\
&b_1=-b_0+1!\\
&b_2=2b_0-2!+2!=2!b_0\\
&b_3=-3!b_0+3!\\
&b_4=4!b_0-4!+4!=4!b_0\;,
\end{align*}$$

and you can guess and prove by induction that in general

$$b_n=\begin{cases}
n!b_0,&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\\
-n!b_0+n!,&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\;.
\end{cases}$$

**Added:** It just occurred to me that we could also change the variable. Let $c_n=\frac{b_n}{n!}$; then after division by $n!$ the recurrence $b_n=-nb_{n-1}+n!$ can be written $c_n=-c_{n-1}+1$. **This** recurrence can easily be solved by any number of techniques, and then it’s just a matter of restoring $b_n$ by multiplying by $n!$.

Comment: If no initial conditions exist is there a way to improvise?

Comment: @user71354: Yes, in this case: see the addition that I just made after thinking about it a little more.

Comment: Bravo, that pattern eluded me!

Answer (score 0):

For the first question, the techniques that Wilf's ["generatingfunctionology"](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/DownldGF.html) present in the second chapter make the solving of such routine.

Answer (score 0):

For the first recurrence, define $A(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} a_n z^n$, write so there aren't subtractions in indices:
$$
a_{n + 2} = 3 a_{n + 1} - 2 a_n + (n + 2)^2 \cdot 2^{n + 2}
$$
If you multiply by $z^n$, sum over $n \ge 0$, you need sums like:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n \ge 0} a_{n + k} z^n 
  &= \frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - \ldots - a_{k - 1} z^{k - 1}}{z^k} \\
\sum_{n \ge 0} n \cdot 2^n
  &= z \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d} z} \frac{1}{1 - 2 z}
\end{align}
The result is:
$$
\frac{A(z) - a_0 - a_1 z}{z^2}
  = 3 \frac{A(z) - a_0}{z}
       - 2 A(z)
       + \frac{16 -56 z + 144 z^2 - 128 z^3}{(A1 - 2 z)^3}
$$
Splitting the result as partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = \frac{18 - a_0 + a_1}{1 - 2 z}
         + \frac{4}{(1 - 2 z)^2}
         - \frac{10}{(1 - 2 z)^3}
         + \frac{4}{(1 - 2 z)^4}
         - \frac{24 - 2 a_0 + a_1}{1 - z}
         + 8
$$
The coefficients can now be read off by the generalized binomial theorem for negative integer powers:
$$
(1 + u)^{-m} = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{-m}{k} u^k
             = \sum_{k \ge 0} \binom{k + m - 1}{m - 1} (-1)^k u^k
$$